# Code Editor API (with line number) and code highlighter

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, html

How to get and open a file **In an Editor with Line Number**
as Below:

So, my text File could open in the editor below and can save my changes on edit.

```
   ---------------------------------------------------------
 1 |                                                       |
 2 |                                                       |
 3 |                                                       |
 4 |                                                       |
 5 |                                                       |
   ---------------------------------------------------------
```

Is there any Code Editor(API/Plugin) available online for doing this?

Comment: I want to create a code editor like this http://code.google.com/apis/gadgets/docs/tools.html#GGE

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I Used [CodeMirror](http://codemirror.net/mode/verilog/index.html). It's the highlighter used by Google for [their API playground](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/).It has given me line number for my code to be editing too.

I've tried it and it works well, and according to their site it works in the following browsers:

- Firefox 1.5 or higher
- Internet Explorer 6 or higher
- Safari 3 or higher
- Opera 9.52 or higher
- Chrome

Cheers !

Answer (score 3):

In addition to CodeMirror, I'm aware of the following:

- [Ace](http://ace.ajax.org/) (formerly Bespin and Skywriter) probably has the most features. Line numbers, auto indentation, code folding, search and replace, themes and other types of customizability. I believe it may use some HTML5 constructs and therefore doesn't have the widest browser support. The demo seems to work, albeit slowly, in IE8. Much nicer experience in FF and Chrome.
- [Editarea](http://www.cdolivet.com/editarea/) has line numbers and syntax highlighting for PHP, CSS, Javascript, Python, HTML, XML, VB, C, CPP, SQL, Pascal, Basic, and Brainf*ck
- For hardcore emacs fans, there's [ymacs](http://www.ymacs.org/), an amazingly faithful AJAX implementation of emacs.

Comment: Is Ace available for free use or commercial?

Comment: It's open source with a BSD license.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a Rails IDE? If so, I'd recommend RubyMine: http://www.jetbrains.com/ruby/

Then under Preferences > Editor > Appearance click "Show line numbers"

Comment: Thanks for answer quoo,But I was asking to create a code editor online by me

Comment: Ah! That makes so much more sense:)